# Issue with mysql connection release in spring data jpa

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

unable to release the connection with mysql in spring data jpa
The properties that I have used is:

Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://hostname/dbname
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=1
spring.jpa.databaseplatform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jta.bitronix.datasource.max-pool-size=25
```

These are the properties which I am using is their any other properties that need to be used.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thankyou

Comment: Please note datasources configured by Spring usually feature some connection pooling, so the connection is kept open for possible reuse. Otherwise clarify what you mean with _unable to release the connection_. In case you got an exception please share the stacktrace.

Comment: I have used jpa repository. when my application is running if i terminate my application within 4 to 5 min  then connection gets released if i terminate my application after 15 + minutes then connection is not getting released. I am checking connection on workbench using command "SELECT db, COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE db = 'dbname' GROUP BY 1;"

Comment: So you still see sessions at mysql server side after the application went down. Where does your application run? Standalone or managed by some sort of container/application server? How did you _terminate_ your application?